# Use case for Thread::getId()?

Tags: java, multithreading

Can someone give me a use case of `Thread's getId()`.

Isn't it better to use `getName()` which would remain same during subsequent runs rather than the which would change ID (basically I can't even debug.)?

Comment: Same thread can be reused, In such a scenario, you would want `Id` rather than `name` so that you understand whether it was the same instance of the same thread or was it a different thread instance all together. This applies particularly when you override the thread name

Comment: @vizsatiz: The numerical thread id is re-used, too. There is no guarantee that once thread-id 1 has died, no other new thread with that id will be created later. The id is unique only for currently existing (not necessarily running) threads. But the thread names are not required to be unique at all, so only the id allows to distinguish the *running* threads. If it is necessary to distinguish threads also historically (in log files), have a look to the sample code in the JavaDoc for ThreadLocal.

Comment: @Gagan: A thread will run only once! When the `run()` method came to an end, the Thread is dead and cannot be revitalised. That means also that the thread id will remain the same during the whole lifetime of the Thread. A Thread from a pool will not die (until it is intended to do so), instead it processes a Task (that might be a Runnable with a `run()` method), but it processes the `run()` method of the Task inside its own `run()` method and will wait otherwise for a new Task, inside its `run()` method.

Comment: and also in case you set the ThreadID by yourself, you can create a mapping. But still , what are you trying to achieve ? just debug messages?

Comment: @vizsatiz, i understand what you are saying, but any practical example ? In what circumstance would i want to check the instance equality using Id ?

Comment: @tquadrat yes you basically taught me the working of a thread pool, but i am sorry i am not able to understand the relation of this with my question, did i missed something ??

Comment: @AntJavaDev we can not set the ThreadID by ourself. All i wanted to understand is the situation where getId() can really be used. So say for example i want to ask a question on getId() from someone, what would that be.

Comment: mostly inside task / thread executors for maintenance and identification, check this [link](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/java.lang.Thread/getId)